# Sort 3 values using macro in C

Tags: c, macros

I tried to use the macro I found here on SO, but, this code gives some errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SWAP(a,b) do {\
int tmp = a; \
   a = b; \
   b = tmp;} while(0)\

#define SORT(a,b,c) \
 if(a > b) { SWAP(a,b) } else if(a > c) { SWAP(a,c) } else if (b>c) { SWAP(b,c) }

int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 2, c = 4;

    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);

    SORT(a,b,c);

    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I remove `do while` from SWAP macro, it works, but gives `2,5,4` instead of `2,4,5`

With `do ... while` loop in SWAP macro, my code gives me errors:

```
Untitled2.c||In function ‘main’:|
Untitled2.c|10|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token|
Untitled2.c|18|note: in expansion of macro ‘SORT’|
Untitled2.c|10|error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’|
Untitled2.c|18|note: in expansion of macro ‘SORT’|
Untitled2.c|10|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token|
Untitled2.c|18|note: in expansion of macro ‘SORT’|
Untitled2.c|10|error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’|
Untitled2.c|18|note: in expansion of macro ‘SORT’|
Untitled2.c|10|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token|
Untitled2.c|18|note: in expansion of macro ‘SORT’|
Untitled2.c|23|error: expected declaration or statement at end of input|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

**EDIT:**

Modified the code, but the result is wrong, the code gives me `2,5,4` instead of `2,4,5`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SWAP(a,b) do {\
int tmp = a; \
   a = b; \
   b = tmp;} while(0);

#define SORT(a,b,c) \
 if(a > b) { SWAP(a,b); } else if(a > c) { SWAP(a,c); } else if (b>c) { SWAP(b,c) }


int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 2, c = 4;

    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);

    SORT(a,b,c);

    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is easy to see, that in any case you only perform one single swap. It is not possible to sort three values (ascending) with one swap. Try it: (2,3,1)

Comment: You can this trick to swap `a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b;`

Comment: Any reason why you can't do this with functions instead of macros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `;` after `SWAP(a,c)` and `SWAP(b,c)` in the `SORT` macro.

Also here

```
#define SORT(a,b,c) \
     if(a > b) { SWAP(a,b) } else if(a > c) { SWAP(a,c) } else if (b>c) { SWAP(b,c) }
```

Using `else` is wrong. In order to sort three valueas `a`, `b` and `c`, it should be

```
#define SORT(a,b,c) \
     {                          \
       if((a) > (b)) { SWAP(a,b); } \
       if((a) > (c)) { SWAP(a,c); } \
       if((b) > (c)) { SWAP(b,c); } \
     }
```

**EDIT**

Added `(` `)` for `a`, `b` and `c` as they may represent complex expressions.

Comment: It's not "you don't need else", it's rather "it's wrong".

Comment: You should put a `do { ... } while(0)` enclosure in your macro or else you risk problems.

Comment: And if the `SWAP` macros has the `do {...} while(0)` construct, you don't need to put `{ }` around their invocations in the `if` cascade. No need to clutter when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need a semi-colon to terminate the do-while loop.

```
   b = tmp;} while(0); 
                     ^ here
```

Your `swap` logic is also wrong. define it as:

```
 if(a > b) { SWAP(a,b) } if(b > c) { SWAP(b,c) } if (a>b) { SWAP(a,b) }
```

But...

The whole marco thing is quite messy. You are better off using the if-else statements directly or use a simpl `inline` function.

Macros are simple textual replacement and have many inherent problems:
 - they are not typesafe.
 - macros arguments which have side-effects would lead to unexpected issues. Consider:

```
 #define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))

 SQR(x++);
```

Generally, avoid macros unless you really don't have any other option.

Comment: Ok, I figured this out, but still the result is wrong

Comment: The usual style is to **not** use a semi-colon after the `do { /* ... */ } while(0)` in the macro. This forces you to place a semi-colon after the macro _call_. Basically, the `do { /* ... */ } while(0)` construct is only useful in a macro when you want to force the programmer to place a semi-colon after the macro call, so adding the semi-colon within the macro itself defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra continuation character `\` at the end of the first macro. And you need semicolons after `SWAP()` because you have `while (0)`.

This way the macros will behave as if they were functions

```
#define SWAP(a, b) \
    do {           \
        int d;     \
        d = a;     \
        a = b;     \
        b = d;     \
    } while (0)

#define SORT(a, b, c)      \
    do {                   \
        if (a > b)         \
            SWAP(a, b);    \
        else if (a > c)    \
            SWAP(a, c);    \
        else if (b > c)    \
            SWAP(b, c);    \
     } while (0)
```

The purpose of `do { ... } while (0)` is to terminate a multi-statement macro with a semicolon, of course in the case of `SWAP` it also provides a scope for the temporary variable `d`. But for the scope you could just use braces `{ ... }` but then adding a semicolon at the end of the macro invocation would create an empty statement, thus `do { ... } while (0)` is a nice trick to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end your while loop with semicolon: `while(0);`

Comment: Ok, I figured this out, but still the result is wrong

Answer (score 1):

lets check your sort macro:

`a=5, b=2, c=4`

```
if(a > b) {
   SWAP(a,b)
} else if(a > c) {
   SWAP(a,c)
} else if (b>c) {
   SWAP(b,c)
}
```

a is greater then b -> they will be swapped.
`a=2, b=5, c=4`
the rest are `else`. so it won't do anything else

Answer (score 0):

In line 9,adding macros for sort when it was called the loop terminated after performing if condition,As you used else later.
So Here is the point that you should use all conditions as if.
better suggestion here to use recursion method for sort :)